# Como carregar um projeto no Laravel numa versão antiga?

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web

Tenho um projeto feito no Framework Laravel 5.4 e recentemente o Laravel fez uma atualização para o 5.5, ao passar meu projeto para outro computador, ficou instalado o Laravel 5.5 nesse PC, agora eu não consigo trabalhar nesse projeto.

Ao dar o comando

```
php artisan serve
```

Ele retorna este erro:

> PHP parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or
>   variable  in
>   C:\Users\Nome_do_Usuario\Nome_do_Projeto\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php
>   on line 444

Como eu faço para carregar um projeto de uma versão antiga do laravel em um computador que tem a versão do laravel mais recente?

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema semelhante agora, mas para criar um projeto na versão 5.2

A partir do comentário:

> Você pode tentar utilizando o composer:
>
> php composer create-project laravel/laravel nome_do_projeto "5.4"

Cheguei ao comando:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel nome_do_projeto "5.2"`

porém apresentou um erro, e funcionou ao modificar para:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel nome_do_projeto "5.2.*"`

Answer (score 0):

O problema esta na linha:

```
 function event(...$args)
 {
    return app('events')->fire(...$args);
 }
```

Verifique se a sua versão do php é superior a 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizando o [composer](https://getcomposer.org/):

```
php composer create-project laravel/laravel nome_do_projeto "5.4"
```

Ou direto no arquivo composer.json:

```
"require": {
     "php": ">=5.6.4",
     "laravel/framework": "5.4",
     "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
```

Desta forma você limita a versão do laravel para a 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Apague seu arquivo composer.lock e depois roda o seguinte comando:

```
composer update;
```

ou

```
composer install;
```