# Criar projeto no Laravel em versão anterior

Tags: laravel

Quando crio um projeto no Laravel este vem na versão 5.5, porém estou seguindo um tutorial e o código da erro para executar.

Acredito que seja pois no tutorial é utilizado a versão 5.2 do Laravel.

Resolvi então criar um projeto com a versão 5.2, lendo [este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245311/como-carregar-um-projeto-no-laravel-numa-vers%C3%A3o-antiga) cheguei a este comando:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel apiLaravel "5.2"`

E a principio parecia estar tudo certo, até o `Fatal error` exibido no final.

```
D:\wamp64\www\laravel>composer create-project laravel/laravel apiLaravel "5.2"
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.0)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.2.0): Downloading (100%)
Created project in apiLaravel
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> php artisan clear-compiled

Warning: require(D:\wamp64\www\laravel\apiLaravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.p
hp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp64\www\laravel\a
piLaravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\wamp64\www\laravel\apiLarave
l\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\wamp64\
www\laravel\apiLaravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned wit
h error code 255
```

Será que falta alguma configuração ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Parece permissão de pasta ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic executei o cmd como administrador agora e deu o mesmo erro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tenta utilizar desta forma:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.2.*"
```

Método passado direto da documentação do [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2#installing-laravel)

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver modificando o comando:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel apiLaravel "5.2"`

para

`composer create-project laravel/laravel apiLaravel "5.2.*"`